# Неправильный перевод для прошедшего времени в уведомлении об окончании выборов модераторов

Tags: дефект, локализация, выборы, предстоящие-события

Должно быть "закончились", а не "заканчиваются"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне кажется, тут проблема в другом месте начинается. Почему в разделе "Предстоящие события" оказалось событие из прошлого?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ возможно стоит заменить метку [предстоящие-события] на [блок-важных-вопросов].

Comment: @Зонтик это же разные сущности

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Просто мне показалось, что ну очень похожие темы у меток. В прочем, *модератор большой, ему видней* =)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Потому что у меня вкладка была открыта, а когда я вернулся 2 часа прошло с момента окончания, но к сачстью я успел заскринить т.к. после повтороного открытия страницы, она пропала

Comment: Такое поведение вряд ли будут исправлять. Что-то подобное (про оставленную надолго открытой страницу) и обновление уже было на Мете давным давно. Можно поискать, но емнип, это посчитали минорным и не требующем какой-то реакции. Ну и про "забытую" вкладку надо бы добавить в текст вопроса, это важный нюанс.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Тогда можешь пожалуйста поставить метку "так задумано"?

Comment: Да, теперь легко :) Хотя я всё же не уверен, что надо именно [meta-tag:статус-так-задумано], скорее [meta-tag:статус-не-желаем-исправлять]. Хочу ещё придумать метку для таких ситуаций обновления страницы без явного F5. И заодно повесить её на старый вопрос (если удастся его найти).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Вообще уже есть метка "статус-отклонено" можно его использовать, чтобы не создавать новую. Потому что явного отличия пока не вижу между существующим и тем что ты предлагаешь. Но тебе виднее :)

Comment: Да. Спасибо за подсказку. Указал её в ответе с соответствующими пояснениями.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сама картинка выглядит странно по той причине, что **событие из прошлого** отображается в блоке **"Предстоящие события"**.

Т.к. ситуация возникла из-за автоматического (без явной перезагрузки страницы) обновления даты. Ситуация, имхо, является достаточно редкой, потому что не вся новая информация подкачивается без явного перезапроса страницы. Поэтому, я не думаю, что с таким поведением будут что-то делать.

Тем не менее не могу сказать, что это [статус-так-задумано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be), а скорее какой-то [статус-отклонено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be). Хотя подобные метки, кмк, должны ставить в первую очередь сотрудники, а не волонтёры-модераторы.

Пытаться "править" это дело через перевод нельзя, т.к. в бизнес-логике нет разделения для будущих событий (когда дата в будущем) и прошедших (когда дата в прошлом). Есть только одна строка про будущее. "Починив" её для описанного случая мы сломаем вариант с предстоящими событиями.

Comment: "Хотя подобные метки, кмк, должны ставить в первую очередь сотрудники, а не волонтёры-модераторы" - красные метки они как раз именно для модераторов :) https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags

Comment: Значит пусть будет "статус-отклонено". Тем более все пояснения ты уже дал, так что вопросов возникать не должно как по мне

Comment: @EzioMercer так сотрудники по дефолту являются обладателями "ромба", т.е. модераторами. Хотя есть и исключения.

Comment: А, ты с этой точки зрения это написал, тогда понятно, нет вопросов :) Но на основной мете модераторы-волонтёры сами закрывают такими тегами, если считают нужным

Comment: @EzioMercer мне это не всегда понятно, может там у кого-то есть подвязки на реальных сотрудников. Но если исходить, что их нет, мне кажется неправильным решать отклонять какую-то фичу, которую в принципе делать могут всё равно совершенно другие люди, над которыми у тебя нет власти.

Comment: Не вижу оснований для метки [статус-отклонено]. Если дефект действительно есть, решение об отклонении могут принять только разработчики, если посчитают допустим, что его слишком сложно исправлять. То, что дефект редкий, не основание для отклонения.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight в целом согласен (см. мой коммент выше). Но я даже мод.соглашение ещё не принял :)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, да вы правы, но αλεχολυτ уже сказал выше, что такое обсуждалось на основной мете и там решили забить на это, потому конкртено в этом вопросе вполне корректно вешать "статус-отклонено"

Comment: @EzioMercer только я не говорил, что "такое обсуждалось на основной мете".

Comment: А что тогда означает [этот комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12599/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc/12607?noredirect=1#comment54549_12599) ?

Comment: А, или "Мета" в том комментарии наша Мета имелась ввиду? Я просто из-за "это посчитали минорным и не требующем какой-то реакции" подумал что так решили на основной Мете, т.к. на функционал мы тут не можем влиять, только на основной Мете

Comment: @EzioMercer "Мета" - да, наша. Про главную я обычно пишу MSE, про enSO - MSO.

Comment: Тогда это странно, почему тут приняли решение не реагировать на такое поведение? Может если сообщить об этом, на основной мете всё же посчитают это нужным? По ключевым словам я не нашёл такого обсуждения, если его действительно нет, то думаю стоит открыть такой вопрос

Comment: @EzioMercer можешь попробовать. Я плюсану по-любому. Но возможную реакцию сотрудников я уже предсказал выше. Будь готов к этому.

Comment: @EzioMercer случайно удалил твой коммент, а восстановить пока не могу. Постить надо на **meta.stackexchange.com** (не meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Хахаха, главное не забыть восстановить :) Я интересовался на счёт этого у них там и нашёл обсуждение, где ответили что постить можно куда хочешь, дальше твой вопрос либо перенесут либо оставят как есть и потому не надо думать три часа куда же постить ответ. Потому с тех пор я всё публикую на `meta.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: @EzioMercer MSE лучше хотя бы тем, что там репутация есть. Если перенесут, то будет, а если не перенесут, то не будет.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ А, не знал об этом :) Думал это мета просто для других вопросов, буду знать на будущее, спасибо!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Тот коммент можешь не восстанавливать :) [Вопрос на stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388530/upcoming-events-are-not-updating-correctly)